# Validate worksheet name using WATiR

Tags: automated-testing, watir, watir-webdriver

How to validate the worksheet name / file name of Excel and CSV files in WATiR?

Because if we save the CSV file in with different name, the worksheet name will also change while in Excel it will remain the same.

How we can find the File name if we will open the file?

Comment: Do you have a piece of code to demonstrate what you are working on?

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't had to do this in a few years, I always found the win32OLE to be my best friend in these cases.  Can't seem to find any of my old code samples.  Doing a quick search, I came across a fairly good tutorial [here](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/03/27/using-ruby-and-win32ole-to-manipulate-excel/) by David Sulc with [this particular post](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/03/27/win32ole-and-ruby-working-with-worksheets/) seeming to cover exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Watir drives browsers. Since you are using Watir my guess is that you are using Ruby. If you need to access Excel files you will have to use another tool, [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) for example.